# Можно ли как-то поместить иконки в jar, чтобы было проще его передать на другой компьютер?

Tags: java, swing

У меня Maven-проект. Я положила иконки в папку src\main\resources, прописала такие же пути к ним, но созданный jar-архив их не видит. Когда запускаю jar, все работает, но иконки не отображаются. Из ИДЕИ все нормально грузится.
Файлы изображений попадают в корень jar-архива. Может быть как-то нужно пути прописать по другому? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить *URL* ресурса используйте **getClass().getResource()**;

```
getClass().getResource("/images/bomb.gif")
```

Сначала файл будет искаться в **classpath**/images/bomb.gif

если не найден то в: **jar-файл**/images/bomb.gif

Comment: Сейчас у меня прописано так: `wiki = new JMenuItem("Википедия", new ImageIcon("src\\main\\resources\\images\\wiki.png"));`, если я пишу: `wiki = new JMenuItem("Википедия", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/wiki.png")));` получаю ошибку NullPointerException. Я понимаю, что писать нужно как-то по другому, но не могу понять как. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Хотя, в таком виде созданный jar видит иконку. Но в IntelliJ IDEA приложение не работает по причине NullPointerException. Что-то мне подсказывает, что моя IDEA не признает прямой слэш. Может в настройках это где решается?

Comment: @AliceMagic nullPointerException в IDEA скорее всего из за того, что файл ищется в classpath, и его там нет. Не указывайте \\ в путях)

Comment: Denis, nullPointerException появляется только когда я пишу "/images/wiki.png". С двойным обратным слэшем как раз таки все нормально.

Comment: Чудеса! Как-то вдруг само начало нормально работать. NullPointerException перестал вылетать сам собой))

Comment: Сама теперь не пойму, где я косячила))) Спасибо огромное всем!